# apply function in R

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I want to apply a user defined function over a matrix object.
I don't have desired results my input is a 4x4 matrix and I want to get as output a 4x4 matrix with the transformation defined in mapfun function

Where is my error?

Thanks in advance

```
mapfun <- function(val){
if (val == 1){
 res <- "A"  }
else{
 if (val == 2){
   res <- "B"
 } else
 {
   if (val == 3){
     res <- "C"
   } else
   {
    res <- "D"
  }
  }
}
return(res)
}

mat1 <- matrix(sample(c(1,2,3,4), 16, replace=T,  prob=c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)),
          nrow=4, ncol=4)

mat2 <- apply(mat1, 1, FUN=mapfun)`
```

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `apply(mat1,c(1,2),FUN=mapfun)`.

Answer (score 3):

We can just the numeric values in 'mat1' as index to replace the corresponding 'LETTERS'.  The output will be a `vector` which can be converted back to a `matrix` by assigning `dim`.

```
`dim<-`(LETTERS[mat1], dim(mat1))
```

Regarding the Warning message in the `mapfun`, it would be better to use `ifelse` instead of `if/else` as we are dealing with a `vector` of length greater than 1 in each row of 'mat1'.

```
 mapfun <- function(val){
  ifelse(val == 1, 'A', 
        ifelse(val==2, 'B',
           ifelse(val==3, 'C', 'D')))
   }
apply(mat1, 1, mapfun)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably work:

```
mat1[] <- mapply(mapfun,mat1)
```

Note that this will modify `mat1`, so you could make a copy of `mat1` named `mat2` and apply the function to `mat2`:

```
mat2<- mat1
mat2[] <- mapply(mapfun,mat1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this (fun) solution as well. First you coerce input value to a character vector and then use repeatedly `replace` function and return the result as a matrix again. Maybe there is a way to trick `replace` function so that it would be used only once.

```
mapfun <- function(val) {
  res <- as.character(val)
  res <- replace(x = res, list = which(res == "1"), values = "A")
  res <- replace(x = res, list = which(res == "2"), values = "B")
  res <- replace(x = res, list = which(res == "3"), values = "C")
  res <- replace(x = res, list = which(res == "4"), values = "D")
  return(matrix(res, ncol = 4)) # ncol(val)
}

mat1 <- matrix(sample(c(1,2,3,4), 16, replace=T,  prob=c(0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)),
               nrow=4, ncol=4)
mat1
mapfun(mat1)
```

Comment: You can write this as simply `replace(mat1,seq_along(mat1),LETTERS[mat1])`

Comment: This is just amazing how many  "longer" and "shorter", "worser" and "better" (and and and... ) solutions there are :)